# Calculating suitable area based on product of two binary layers

Tags: qgis, raster, reclassify

In QGIS I am attempting to calculate the suitable area based on two reclassified layers (`Raster tools -> Reclassify by range`) that have been overlaid with `SAGA -> Raster calculus -> Product`. Each layer is for one species, and I am trying to find the overlap area of suitable habitat. I am using binary values for suitability: `0` for unsuitable, `1` for suitable.

So, in the reclassification, each layer has only those two values. In the product, then, suitable habitat for both species (what I'm looking for) will have a product of `1`, and all other values will have a product of `0`.

I am looking for a way to calculate and be able to extract only the total area of overlap where the product is `1`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you've classifies into binary 0/1 layers, and then done the raster calculus->product and produced the binary product layer, then you might be able to get the summary statistics you want from Layer/Properties/Information or from Raster/Miscellanous/Raster Information -- the  Statistics_Mean  times the number of pixels will give you the total area of overlap in pixels, and you could multiply that by the area per pixel to get the area.  Is that the sort of result you are looking for?

Comment: See if the `Processing/Raster Analysis/Raster Layer Unique Values Report` does what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `Processing/Processing Toolbox/Raster Analysis/Raster Unique Values Report` on your Raster Calculus product layer.  It will count and report the total area of the pixels with zeros and ones:

[image]